# how to join specific values of a R data frame

Tags: r

I have a data frame that represents the usage of some equipments as shown in the df sample bellow. One row represents one equipment and each column represents an specific hour of the day. The values above zero are the hours that the equipment is turnned on and the values of zero are when it is turnned off. I need to extract, for each equipment, all periods of time that they where turned on. The problem is that the equipments have different numbers of usage in a same day, and I need to extract those periods for all of them. Does anyone know how to solve that problem?

```
df = data.frame(hour_1 = c(1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1), hour_2 = c(2, 2, 2, 0, 2, 2), hour_3 = c(3, 3, 3, 0, 3, 3),
            hour_5 = c(5, 5, 0, 0, 0, 0), hour_6 = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0), hour_7 = c(0, 0, 0, 7, 7, 0),
            hour_8 = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0), hour_9 = c(9, 9, 0, 0, 9, 9), hour_10 = c(10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10))
```

Comment: Can you show the expected output

Comment: I expect to get the results (1-5, 9-10) for row number one and (2-3, 7, 9-10) for row number 5, for example.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure if I understand you correctly. According to the comment under your question, you want a group of vectors for each machine; one vector for each period that the machine was working, containing the hours that the machine was working. Since the number of vectors may be different for each machine, this won't fit in a data frame.

However, here's a one-liner that will give you a list giving you that information.

```r
lapply(split.data.frame((as.matrix(df)>0), 1:6), function(x) 
       split(which(x), cumsum(c(0, diff(which(x))-1)))) -> machines
```

This produces the following list:

```r
machines
#> $`1`
#> $`1`$`0`
#> [1] 1 2 3 4
#> 
#> $`1`$`3`
#> [1] 8 9
#> 
#> 
#> $`2`
#> $`2`$`0`
#> [1] 1 2 3 4
#> 
#> $`2`$`3`
#> [1] 8 9
#> 
#> 
#> $`3`
#> $`3`$`0`
#> [1] 1 2 3
#> 
#> $`3`$`5`
#> [1] 9
#> 
#> 
#> $`4`
#> $`4`$`0`
#> [1] 6
#> 
#> $`4`$`2`
#> [1] 9
#> 
#> 
#> $`5`
#> $`5`$`0`
#> [1] 2 3
#> 
#> $`5`$`2`
#> [1] 6
#> 
#> $`5`$`3`
#> [1] 8 9
#> 
#> 
#> $`6`
#> $`6`$`0`
#> [1] 1 2 3
#> 
#> $`6`$`4`
#> [1] 8 9
```

So if you want to know when machine 1 was active you can do:

```
machines[[1]]
#> $`0`
#> [1] 1 2 3 4
#>
#> $`3`
#> [1] 8 9
```

This one liner shows how the data can be extracted to give the desired output:

```r
sapply(machines, function(x) 
  paste0("(", paste(sapply(x, 
  function(y){if(length(y)>1) paste(min(y), max(y), sep="-") else y}), collapse = ", "), ')'))
               1                2                3                4 
   "(1-5, 9-10)"    "(1-5, 9-10)"      "(1-3, 10)"        "(7, 10)" 
               5                6 
"(2-3, 7, 9-10)"    "(1-3, 9-10)"
```

Comment: I see. Im sorry,my english is not so good. I need the hours that each equipment is turnned on and off exactly like in the output that I showed before. For the times that the equipment is turned on and off in the same hour, I needed to repeat the value like in the same output.

Comment: See my update,. This is exactly what you asked for.

Answer (score 0):

An option would be to convert to 'long' format andd then do a `filter`

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
df %>%
    pivot_longer(everything()) %>%
    filter(value != 0)
```

---

If we need the index

```
m1 <- which(df > 0, arr.ind = TRUE)
split(colnames(df)[m1[,2]], m1[,1])
```

---

Based on the update OP showed

```
library(data.table)
library(stringr)
df %>%
   mutate(rn = row_number()) %>% 
   pivot_longer(cols = -rn) %>% 
   group_by(grp = rleid(value != 0), rn)  %>%
   filter(any(value != 0)) %>%
   summarise(value = list(range(value))) %>% 
   unnest(c(value)) %>%
   ungroup %>%
    mutate(grp = str_c('period_', match(grp, unique(grp)), letters[rowid(grp)]))
```

Comment: Thank you for your help. But I was expecting the intervals of usage in different columns like in the following df.

df = data.frame (period_1a = c(1, 1, 1, 7,2,1), period_1b = c(5, 5, 3,7, 3,3), period_2a = c(9,9,10, 10,7,9), period_2_b = c(10,10,10,10,7,10), period_3a = c(0,0,0,0,9,0), period_3b = c(0,0,0,0,10,0))